# Adding zero-value records in a query using cumulative analytical functions

Tags: sql, oracle

Input and code:

```
with data as (
  select 1 id, 'A' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2007' year, '04' month, 5 sales from dual union all
  select 2 id, 'Z' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2007' year, '04' month, 99 sales from dual union all
  select 3 id, 'A' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2008' year, '05' month, 10 sales from dual union all
  select 4 id, 'B' name, 'vegetable' r_group, '2008' year,  '07'  month, 20 sales from dual
)

select year,
       month,
       r_group,
       sum(sales) sales,
       sum(opening) opening,
       sum(closing) closing
from (
  select t.*,
         (sum(sales) over (partition by name, r_group
                           order by year, month
                           rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                          ) -sales ) as opening,
         sum(sales) over (partition by name, r_group
                          order by year, month
                          rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                         ) as closing
  from data t
)
group by year, month, r_group
order by year, month
```

Output:

```
year   |   month   |  r_group   | sales   |  opening  |  closing    |
2007   |     04    |    fruit   |  104    |    0      |    104      |
2008   |     05    |    fruit   |  10     |    5      |    15       |
2008   |     07    | vegetable  |  20     |    0      |    20       |
```

I want the output to be like the following:

```
year   |   month   |  r_group   | sales   |  opening  |  closing    |
2007   |     04    |    fruit   |  104    |    0      |    104      |
2008   |     05    |    fruit   |  10     |    104    |    114      |
2008   |     07    | vegetable  |  20     |    0      |    20       |
```

I can achieve the desired output only by adding a zero-valued record in the data for month=05 and for name = 'Z' like this:

```
select 1 id, 'A' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2007', year '04' month, 5 sales from dual union all
select 2 id, 'Z' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2007', year '04' month, 99 sales from dual union all
select 3 id, 'A' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2008', year '05' month, 10 sales from dual union all
select 4 id, 'Z' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2008', year '05' month, 0 sales from dual union all
select 5 id, 'B' name, 'vegetable' r_group, '2008', year '07' month, 20 sales from dual ))
```

However, I want to know if I can do this as part of the select query without having to edit the data itself.

**EDIT**

The inner select statement will input into a database table the detailed version: year, month, name, r_group, opening, closing. In other words the result of this query will be used to populate the db table and then aggregation using the outer query will happen afterwards:

```
select t.*,
         (sum(sales) over (partition by name, r_group
                           order by year, month
                           rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                          ) -sales ) as opening,
         sum(sales) over (partition by name, r_group
                          order by year, month
                          rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                         ) as closing
  from data t
```

then I'll use an aggregate on that using an analytical tool (3rd party) to aggregate on r_group only without including the name. But the year, month, name, r_group detail must exist in the background.

**EDIT 2**

In other workds, I'm trying to dynamically add missing data. For instance, if name = 'Z' exists in 2007,04 but DOES NOT in 2008,05 then the cumulative function will fail once it gets to 2008. Because, it does not have a name ='Z' in 2008 to start with it fails.

Comment: Can you explain the logic for the columns you care about?

Comment: for r_group =  'fruit'  the Opening value for month ='05' should be the Closing value from month = '04' . The the Closing value for month = '05' for r_group = 'fruit' should be Opening value from month = '04'  + sales value for month ='05'.

Comment: As it stands this question is very confusing - you have had 2 answers that give your exact  expected output but you appear to not be interested in that result but in an intermediate step prior to aggregation. You should reconsider what it is you are expecting and generate a [MCVE] for **just** that part of the question (i.e. if you want something from the step before aggregation then write the expected output for that step and **not** for the step afterwards). You possibly need to abandon/delete this question and ask a new (clearer) question.

Comment: These are two interrelated parts of this. The inner has to work for the outer one to work properly. I'm sorry to disagree with you one this one. I can post another question that's not a problem but it will not be very different from this one.

Comment: here is the new quesiton: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838759/dynamically-adding-zero-valued-records-for-subsequent-aps-for-analytical-functio

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, this sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

Group by `R_GROUP`, `YEAR` and `MONTH` first then use the analytical query:

```
SELECT t.*,
       SUM( sales ) OVER ( PARTITION BY r_group ORDER BY year, month ) - sales
         AS opening,
       SUM( sales ) OVER ( PARTITION BY r_group ORDER BY year, month ) AS closing
FROM   (
  SELECT r_group,
         year,
         month,
         SUM( sales ) AS sales
  FROM   data
  GROUP BY r_group, year, month
) t
ORDER BY year, month
```

**Update**:

This will also include the name in the output:

```
SELECT t.*,
       SUM( sales ) OVER ( PARTITION BY r_group, dt ) AS r_group_month_sales,
       COALESCE(
         SUM( sales ) OVER (
           PARTITION BY r_group
           ORDER BY dt
           RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '1' MONTH PRECEDING
         ),
         0
       ) AS opening,
       SUM( sales ) OVER (
         PARTITION BY r_group
         ORDER BY dt
         RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
       ) AS closing
FROM   (
  SELECT d.*,
         TO_DATE( year || month, 'YYYYMM' ) AS dt
  FROM   data d
) t
ORDER BY dt
```

**Output**:

```
ID NAME R_GROUP   YEAR MONTH SALES DT         R_GROUP_MONTH_SALES OPENING CLOSING
-- ---- --------- ---- ----- ----- ---------- ------------------- ------- -------
 1 A    fruit     2007 04        5 2007-04-01                 104       0     104
 2 Z    fruit     2007 04       99 2007-04-01                 104       0     104
 3 A    fruit     2008 05       10 2008-05-01                  10     104     114
 4 B    vegetable 2008 07       20 2008-07-01                  20       0      20
```

You can then do whatever processing you want on the output of this query.

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT year,
       month,
       r_group,
       MAX( r_group_month_sales ) AS sales,
       MAX( opening ) AS opening,
       MAX( closing ) AS closing,
       YOUR_THIRD_PARTY_AGGREGATION_FUNCTION( column_names ) AS other
FROM   (
  -- insert the query above
)
GROUP BY year, month, r_group
ORDER BY year, month
```

Comment: thanks MT0. but in this case I will need to pull in name as well. The year, month, r_group is an aggregation on top of the year, month, name, r_group.

Comment: @bytebiscuit Please can you update your question and expected output as that does not include the `name` column and my query gives the expected output as you currently shown it.

Comment: see Edit in the question

Comment: @bytebiscuit Updated

Comment: MT0, the record for id =1 is wrong. Name= 'A' and R_GROUP = 'gwmb' , YEAR = 2007 , MONTH = 04, SALES = 5, OPENING = 0, CLOSING = 104. This is wrong. It should be OPENING = 0, CLOSING = 5.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of CURRENT ROW you can use PRECEDING keyword to sum till the previous row.

```
with data as (
  select 1 id, 'A' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2007' year, '04' month, 5 sales from dual union all
  select 2 id, 'Z' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2007' year, '04' month, 99 sales from dual union all
  select 3 id, 'A' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2008' year, '05' month, 10 sales from dual union all
  select 4 id, 'B' name, 'vegetable' r_group, '2008' year, '07' month, 20 sales from dual )
select t.*, 
  coalesce(sum(sales) over (partition by  r_group order by year, month rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),0) opening,
  sum(sales) over (partition by  r_group order by year, month rows between unbounded preceding and current row) closing
from (
  select year, month, r_group, sum(sales) sales
  from data
  group by year, month, r_group
  ) t
order by 3,1,2;

year    month   r_group     sales   opening closing
---------------------------------------------------
2007    04      fruit       104     0       104
2008    05      fruit       10      104     114
2008    07      vegetable   20      0       20
```

Comment: Same as MT0's answer. The name must be included as well in the inner select. Otherwise I will not be able to drill down to the details (i.e. name)

Comment: @bytebiscuit Can you please explain what you mean by "being able to drill down to the details"? You are not selecting the `NAME` column in the output of the query in your question so it will never be available to "drill down to" (whatever that may mean).

Comment: This query will input in the database the detailed version: year, month, name, r_group, opening, closing   then I'll use an aggregate on that using an analytical tool (3rd party) to aggregate on r_group only without including the name. But the year, month, name, r_group detail must exist