# Dynamically adding zero-valued records for subsequent APs for analytical function to work

Tags: sql, oracle

```
with data as (
  select 1 id, 'A' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2007' year, '04' month, 5 sales from dual union all
  select 2 id, 'Z' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2007' year, '04' month, 99 sales from dual union all
  select 3 id, 'A' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2008' year, '05' month, 10 sales from dual union all
  select 4 id, 'B' name, 'vegetable' r_group, '2008' year,  '07'  month, 20 sales from dual
)


  select t.*,
         (sum(sales) over (partition by name, r_group
                           order by year, month
                           rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                          ) -sales ) as opening,
         sum(sales) over (partition by name, r_group
                          order by year, month
                          rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                         ) as closing
  from data t
 order by year , month
```

Output will be:

```
year   |   month   |  name   |  r_group   | sales   |  opening  |  closing |
2007   |     04    |   'A'   |   fruit   |  5       |    0      |    5     |
2007   |     04    |   'Z'   | fruit     |  99      |   0       |    99   |
2008   |     05    |   'A'   | fruit     |  10      |   5       |    15    |
2008   |     07    |   'B'   | vegetable |  20      |    0      |    20    |
```

If I aggregate now on top of this select statement using this:

```
select year, month, r_group, sum(sales) sales, sum(opening) opening, sum(closing) closing from (
   select t.*, 
      (sum(sales) over........ 
) 
group by year, month, r_group
order by year, month
```

I get the following result:

```
year   |   month   |  r_group   | sales   |  opening   |  closing |
2007   |     04    |   fruit    |  104    |    0       |    104   |
2008   |     05    |   fruit    |  10     |    5       |    15    |
2008   |     07    | vegetable  |  20     |    0       |    20    |
```

which is **wrong**. Notice that the value of name='Z' has not been taken into account at all in 2008. Since the cumulative function works backwards it didn't have a name='Z' record in 2008 to go backwards with. If I put a zero-value record in 2008, for name = 'Z' then it will work. I want to avoid adding dummy zero-valued records and have this done dynamically in the query. If I add the zero-valued record in the data like this:

```
select 1 id, 'A' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2007', year '04' month, 5 sales from dual union all
select 2 id, 'Z' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2007', year '04' month, 99 sales from dual union all
select 3 id, 'A' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2008', year '05' month, 10 sales from dual union all
select 4 id, 'Z' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2008', year '05' month, 0 sales from dual union all
select 5 id, 'B' name, 'vegetable' r_group, '2008', year '07' month, 20 sales from dual ))
```

then the first query will output:

```
year   |   month   |  name   |  r_group   | sales   |  opening  |  closing |
2007   |     04    |   'A'   |   fruit   |  5       |    0      |    5     |
2007   |     04    |   'Z'   | fruit     |  99      |   0       |    99   |
2008   |     05    |   'A'   | fruit     |  10      |   5       |    15    |
2008   |     05    |   'Z'   | fruit     |  0       |   99      |    99    |
2008   |     07    |   'B'   | vegetable |  20      |    0      |    20    |
```

and If i aggregate again using the second outer select I will get:

```
year   |   month   |  r_group   | sales   |  opening   |  closing |
2007   |     04    |   fruit    |  104    |    0       |    104   |
2008   |     05    |   fruit    |  10     |    104     |    114   |
2008   |     07    | vegetable  |  20     |    0       |    20    |
```

which is correct. However, as I mentioned, I do not want to add zero-valued records. There is discussion on just this topic here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:8912311513313 but I haven't been able to make this work.

Comment: Can you please not mark this as a duplicate. I'm the owner of the other question as well. That question was voted as not clear enough, hence why I had to open this one.

Comment: I don't see how this is different to the old one? OK, you've taken out the aggregation from the first query, but then you still talk about it. I'm not sure it's any clearer. Why is this one talking about aggregation at all if the intent was to focus on the inner part?

Comment: The output that was required in the last post was at the aggregate level rather than the detail inner sql statement level - this caused confusion in the other question. Can you please close the other question and leave this open. Thank you.

Comment: just to keep new readers informed about what the expected output should be for both cases as they depend on each other. Is this really that difficult to understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fairly simplistic approach (and similar to what that AskTom link shows) is to extract all the year/month pairs, and all the name/r_group pairs, and then cross-join those:

```
with data as (
  select 1 id, 'A' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2007' year, '04' month, 5 sales from dual union all
  select 2 id, 'Z' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2007' year, '04' month, 99 sales from dual union all
  select 3 id, 'A' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2008' year, '05' month, 10 sales from dual union all
  select 4 id, 'B' name, 'vegetable' r_group, '2008' year, '07' month, 20 sales from dual
)
select a.year, a.month, b.name, b.r_group, nvl(d.sales, 0) as sales
from (select distinct year, month from data) a
cross join (select distinct name, r_group from data) b
left join data d on d.year = a.year and d.month = a.month and d.name = b.name and d.r_group = b.r_group
order by year, month, name, r_group;

YEAR MO N R_GROUP        SALES
---- -- - --------- ----------
2007 04 A fruit              5
2007 04 B vegetable          0
2007 04 Z fruit             99
2008 05 A fruit             10
2008 05 B vegetable          0
2008 05 Z fruit              0
2008 07 A fruit              0
2008 07 B vegetable         20
2008 07 Z fruit              0
```

But that produces more rows than you wanted with your first level fo aggregation:

```
YEAR MO N R_GROUP        SALES    OPENING    CLOSING
---- -- - --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2007 04 A fruit              5          0          5
2007 04 B vegetable          0          0          0
2007 04 Z fruit             99          0         99
2008 05 A fruit             10          5         15
2008 05 B vegetable          0          0          0
2008 05 Z fruit              0         99         99
2008 07 A fruit              0         15         15
2008 07 B vegetable         20          0         20
2008 07 Z fruit              0         99         99
```

and when aggregated with your second level (from the other query) would produce extra rows for, say, 2007/04/vegetable:

```
YEAR MO R_GROUP        SALES    OPENING    CLOSING
---- -- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2007 04 fruit            104          0        104
2007 04 vegetable          0          0          0
2008 05 fruit             10        104        114
2008 05 vegetable          0          0          0
2008 07 fruit              0        114        114
2008 07 vegetable         20          0         20
```

which you could partially filter those out before aggregating because all the intermediate columns would be zero:

```
with data as (
  select 1 id, 'A' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2007' year, '04' month, 5 sales from dual union all
  select 2 id, 'Z' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2007' year, '04' month, 99 sales from dual union all
  select 3 id, 'A' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2008' year, '05' month, 10 sales from dual union all
  select 4 id, 'B' name, 'vegetable' r_group, '2008' year, '07' month, 20 sales from dual
)
select year,
       month,
       r_group,
       sum(sales) sales,
       sum(opening) opening,
       sum(closing) closing
from (
  select t.*,
         (sum(sales) over (partition by name, r_group
                           order by year, month
                           rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                          ) -sales ) as opening,
         sum(sales) over (partition by name, r_group
                          order by year, month
                          rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                         ) as closing
  from (
    select a.year, a.month, b.name, b.r_group, nvl(d.sales, 0) as sales
    from (select distinct year, month from data) a
    cross join (select distinct name, r_group from data) b
    left join data d
    on d.year = a.year and d.month = a.month and d.name = b.name and d.r_group = b.r_group
  ) t
)
where sales != 0 or opening != 0 or closing != 0
group by year, month, r_group
order by year, month;
```

to get:

```
YEAR MO R_GROUP        SALES    OPENING    CLOSING
---- -- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2007 04 fruit            104          0        104
2008 05 fruit             10        104        114
2008 07 fruit              0        114        114
2008 07 vegetable         20          0         20
```

You could further filter that result to remove rows where the aggregated sales value is still zero, though if you're doing that the filter *before* aggregation isn't needed any more; but it's still a bit messy. And it isn't clear if your outermost aggregation can be modified to do that.

Comment: Thanks a ton Alex, this works just as I expected :) .

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using a [partitioned outer join](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=312) - but first you have to find the distinct name/r_group combinations and then partition outer join accordingly:

```
with data as (select 1 id, 'A' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2007' year, '04' month, 5 sales from dual union all
              select 2 id, 'Z' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2007' year, '04' month, 99 sales from dual union all
              select 3 id, 'A' name, 'fruit' r_group, '2008' year, '05' month, 10 sales from dual union all
              select 4 id, 'B' name, 'vegetable' r_group, '2008' year,  '07'  month, 20 sales from dual),
    data2 as (select distinct name, r_group
              from   data),
      res as (select d.year,
                     d.month,
                     d2.r_group,
                     d.id,
                     d2.name,
                     nvl(d.sales, 0) sales,
                     sum(nvl(d.sales, 0)) over (partition by d2.name, d2.r_group
                                             order by d.year, d.month
                                             rows between unbounded preceding and current row) - nvl(d.sales,0) as opening,
                     sum(nvl(d.sales, 0)) over (partition by d2.name, d2.r_group
                                             order by d.year, d.month
                                             rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as closing
              from   data2 d2
                     left outer join data d partition by (d.year, d.month) on (d.name = d2.name and d.r_group = d2.r_group))
select   year,
         month,
         r_group,
         sum(sales) sales,
         sum(opening) opening,
         sum(closing) closing
from     res
where    sales != 0
or       opening != 0
or       closing != 0
group by year,
         month,
         r_group
order by year,
         month;

YEAR MONTH R_GROUP        SALES    OPENING    CLOSING
---- ----- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2007 04    fruit            104          0        104
2008 05    fruit             10        104        114
2008 07    fruit              0        114        114
2008 07    vegetable         20          0         20
```

This is very similar to Alex's answer, but the use of the partition outer join negates the need to find the distinct year/month pairs, as that is taken care of in the join clause.

Comment: Something I need to learn more about... think I've only seen that used once or twice before.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yeah, I think I've only come across scenarios that require it on forums; I can't remember ever using it in anger in production code (although with my memory, anything is possible!). It's a pretty neat bit of SQL trickery, IMHO. (I always have to refer back to that link in order to work out which bits go in the partition clause, though! *{;-) )

Comment: @AlexPoole Huh, I just did a search in my code and there are two instances where I've used the partition outer join. Clearly I need a memory upgrade or something...